# selectInput can't populate duplicate values (using uiOutput and renderUI) in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app based on a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  ID       Date      result
  1      1/1/2010    100
  1      12/12/2010  200
  2      1/1/2011    300
  2      1/1/2011    400
```

Notice the double ID's...and for ID 2, two dates are the same.

When running, the app looks like this:

[image]

But the app gets confused when it is forced to consider ID #2, which has multiple of the same Dates:

[image]

The dropdown menu has a blank first choice, but the second choice is populated correct.

How could I correct this, so that the dropdown is populated with any number of identical dates?

(The more I think about this, it is feeling like a bug as opposed to simply wrangling functionality out of the object. It isn't hard to think of numerous situations where duplicate values would be of interest.)

Thanks for your attention.

**app.R**

```
library('shiny')

DF <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2), Date=c('1/1/2010', '12/12/2010', '1/1/2011', '1/1/2011'), result=c(100, 200, 300, 400))
DF$Date <- as.character(DF$Date)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

  get_id <- reactive({
    id <- DF[which(DF$ID == input$ID), ]
    return(id)})

  output$result <- renderText({ 
    ans <- get_id()
    print(ans)
    paste("Result: ", ans$result)})


  output$dates<-renderUI({
    print(get_id()$Date)
    selectInput('dates', 'Select date:', choices=get_id()$Date, selected=get_id()$Date[1])})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(2,
      numericInput(inputId="ID", label="Pick an ID: ", value=1))),
           column(2, 
      uiOutput("dates")),
          column(3, mainPanel(textOutput("result")))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why it isn't showing, but there is a get-around for your situation. Use the parameter `selectize = FALSE` in your `selectInput()` function. This should give you the desired functionality.

```
selectInput('dates', 'Select date:', choices=get_id()$Date,selected=get_id()$Date, selectize = FALSE)})
```

Comment: Amazing, simple little fix works. The documentation merely states `selectize: Whether to use selectize.js or not.`  I don't think I would have figured this out without your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like selectize recently added support to allow duplicate values (see github issue https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/129)

But it looks like shiny hasn't picked up that version yet (github issue https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/518)

Comment: So I think what this mean, is that Shiny supports having the duplicate values displayed with respect to choices (eg, `A`, `B`, `B` are valid options to choose for the `selectInput`), but the outputs can't be sent through (ie, Shiny can't handle duplicates of the selection/results).